# Should electrical wiring be placed above or below plumbing pipes

Tags: plumbing, wiring, bathroom

I'm putting a bathroom in my garage/shop. I'm going to have to run wiring and water supply plumbing through the same walls. should I put the wiring above or below plumbing?

Comment: Typically, the answer is neither. You run both in the ceiling or under the floor, and then drop them down separate stud bays to both minimize risk and make installation and repairs easier. Drilling lots of holes in studs is a pain, especially for a non-flexible pipe, much easier to drill one top plate.

Answer (score 3):

It makes absolutely NO difference. Even if the water pipes broke and flooded the stud bay the cable would not typically be damaged or harmed. NOR would it"short out" even in the slightest, even if it got into a device box.

Worrying about having electric and plumbing in the wall together is tantamount to worrying about having gas in the gas tank of your car with the exhaust 6" away.

Answer (score 2):

Your insulation (particularly batt varieties) would absorb the leaking water and thus allow it to travel up to the electrical lines anyway. That's also in conjunction to the propulsion of your, typically 50 psi, water pressure... essentially, a burst or cracked water line would jet the water in any/all possible directions within the wall, further aiding the upward spread/insulation absorption. So you'd have to put your electrical lines, switches and outlets clear up near the ceiling (or at the least on the top side of your "fire blocks") to mitigate any potential contact as far as is possible... which I feel certain wouldn't meet NEC/all other applicable codes (not to mention would be quite inconvenient and 'unsightly' by the measure of most. lol).

Answer (score 1):

I would think in a perfect world I would always have electric above plumbing so that if you have any floods or leaks that there isn't a short.  The chances of it mattering are almost zero since electric is insulated.  The water would basically have to come in around the outlet.  Since you cannot always pick the height of your outlet (you won't have normal room outlets 3 feet off the ground) it is sometimes not possible.  NEC code mentions no issues with either install but again would put plumbing lower.

Comment: Agreed, ideally/logically, water under the wires.

Comment: Electrical getting wet is never a good thing, but it WILL NOT short out as you state. Go to YouTube and search for "hair dryer under water" for proof.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey - rust doesn't create shorts?

Comment: No, I said a flood will not create shorts. Who said anything about rust?

Comment: @SpeedyPetey - the problems I have had caused by water was a slow leak causing rust.

Comment: @DMoore, I was responding to the first sentence in your answer: "I would think in a perfect world I would always have electric above plumbing so that if you have any floods or leaks that there isn't a short." This implies that electrical getting wet will cause a short. This is simply not so.

Answer (score 0):

I think it s best to put some kind of outdoor flexialbe pvc electrical cover over it. You can slice it long ways and wrap it around just to take that extra precaution. If a new build then I would run different places to protect any burst, but the wires are insulated twice on a 12- gage or 14 gage  up so only a box with heavy spray might get inside a nut then the breaker would triger if its all grounded to code. Good luck.